# Permissions on SQL Server FILESTREAM

Tags: sql-server, sqlfilestream

Now I've got a question for you. I'm running a ASP.NET REST Web API using OWIN running as a windows service. Now I've got SQL Server running on a different host, containing a table with binary data and FILESTREAM enabled.

I want to pass this binary data from the web API to the caller. How do I get owin to access SQL Server with credentials that can access the FILESTREAM?

Appreciate your help!